# How to make carriage on large orders free of charge?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Below is a function to get the carriage cost at the point of checkout. It's returning a carriage cost based on a few things/get functions however; if the value of the cart is >=£100 ('p.price') then I need to return the value of '£0.00' else use the function as normal i.e `$query->row('total')` I think :/

```
function get_cart_total($cartID) {
         $this->db->select('SUM((COALESCE(NULLIF(sc.override_price_from_auction, 0), p.price))*sc.quantity) AS total',FALSE);
         $this->db->join('products AS p', 'sc.product_id = p.product_id');
         $this->db->where('sc.cart_id',$cartID);
         $query = $this->db->get('shopping_cart AS sc');
         return $query->row('total');


     function total_with_VAT($cartID, $taxAmount) {
         $total = $this->get_cart_total($cartID);
         $tax_inclusive_total = $total;
         return $tax_inclusive_total;
     }

     function carriage_cost($cartID) {
         $this->db->select('SUM(p.carriage*sc.quantity) AS total',FALSE);
         $this->db->join('products AS p', 'sc.product_id = p.product_id');
         $this->db->where('sc.cart_id',$cartID);
         $query = $this->db->get('shopping_cart AS sc');
         $query->row('total');
         //echo $this->db->last_query();
         return $query->row('total');
     }
```

Comment: good place to throw in an if statement

Comment: Do you just mean if $query->row('total') is greater than 100 or if sc.quantity is greater than 100?

Comment: How should we know? Table structure? Object properties in `$this`? Nowhere near enough information

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Where are you stuck?  What is this "carriage fee" you're talking about?  Is that what this returns?  So, if `$query->row('total')` is greater than `100`, you want it to return `0`?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: I'm assuming `$this` is CodeIgniter.  This looks like CodeIgniter active record code.

Comment: Hi. I mean if sc.quantity is greater than 100 then rather than return the `$query->row('total')` return '£0.00' else actually return `$query->row('total')`

Comment: And yes... it's codeigniter. I'm trying to help a friend with his website. Your help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: @halfer, there you go. Hopefully I can get some help. I think I have the general gist of what to do i.e 'if' 'elseif' - I just cant get the formatting right :(

Comment: What are `p.carriage` and `sc.quantity`?  Which value are you looking at to see if it's `> 100`?  Would this work: `$total = $query->row()->total;  return $total >= 100 ? 0 : $total;`?  Or do you need to check one of the other values?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I've trimmed it a bit more, improved the title, and cast a reopen vote. Feel free to reject any of my edits, but @Rocket's comment would be what I would add as an answer anyway.

Comment: I think you didn't mean `sc.quantity` in the text part of your question, I think you meant `total` (it is the only column available from that query). No matter, try Rocket's solution.

Comment: I've got it I think. There is another function further up for get_cart_total - the  product price is in there `p.price`. `sc.quanity` is multiplied by `p.carraige` to actually get the carriage cost  SO, I've been going back and forward trying to get a total from the function itself. I need to say. If `$query->row('total')` of function `get_cart_total` is >= £100 don't execute function `carriage_cost` OR return a £0.00 value within carraige_cost `$query->row('total')`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can just simply check the value of `total`.

```
function carriage_cost($cartID) {
    $this->db->select('SUM(p.carriage*sc.quantity) AS total',FALSE);
    $this->db->join('products AS p', 'sc.product_id = p.product_id');
    $this->db->where('sc.cart_id',$cartID);
    $query = $this->db->get('shopping_cart AS sc');

    $total = $query->row()->total;
    return $total >= 100 ? 0 : $total;
}
```